# Imageview corner radius not set

Tags: ios, swift

I've created an `imageView` in the interface builder and then set the corner radius in my `UITableViewCell` subclass. However it doesn't seem to apply? The image is set but no corner radius?

**In awakeFromNib**

```
homeBackground?.image = UIImage(named: "score.png")
homeBackground?.layer.masksToBounds = true
homeBackground?.clipsToBounds = true
homeBackground?.layer.cornerRadius = 25
```

Comment: are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: not on this particular imageview

Comment: can you please try put this the code at layOutSubviews?

Comment: How big is the image view?

Comment: the imageview is 50x50 and the image is 1x1 redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set `clipSubviews` property of `UIImageView` to YES.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try placing this at your subclass

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    homeBackground?.image = UIImage(named: "score.png")
    homeBackground?.layer.masksToBounds = true
    homeBackground?.clipsToBounds = true
    homeBackground?.layer.cornerRadius = 25
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the subclass is declared as the class of the cell? via interface builder + at cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: yep all other elements are working fine, so this isnt the issue.

Comment: I just checked your code, work on my CV perfectly. over the interface Builder, click the cell - and check "clip Subviews" over the inspector, and try again

Comment: It does not make difference. This method will be called whenever orientation get changed.

Comment: ya i know @LucasHuang, we are looking for a different way getting this, i'll edit the answer when we figure this out. Feel free to upvote again

Comment: clip subviews didnt help

Comment: it works fine when i said backgroundcolor instead of image, however not with an image